# Javascript not working without an internet connection in IE9

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, iis-7.5

I have published a website on a laptop with IIS 7.5 running IE9. When I have the internet plugged in the website works fine. The weird thing is that it will work fine in firefox weither the machine has internet or not.
Some other information that may be helpful.
Running Windows 7 64Bit. Latest version of firefox. IE9.
Not sure what else you may need. I have tried checking IE permissions but there may be something I have missed so any help will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
@*----------------- JQUERY UI for Accordion  Starts here-------------------- *@
<link href="../../Content/themes/Blue/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.1.custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@* -----------JQUERY UI for Accordion  Ends here--------------------- *@ @*----------------- JQUERY UI for Delete Dialog  Starts here-------------------- *@
<script src="../../Scripts/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@* <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>*@
<script src="../../Scripts/external/jquery-ui.js">></script>
@*----------------- JQUERY UI for Delete Dialog  Ends here-------------------- *@
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@*
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
*@ @* ----------- Scripts added for Devexpress but commented because JQUERY UI not working --------------------- *@
@* 
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>

 *@ @* ----------- Scripts added for Devexpress ends here--------------------- *@
@Html.DevExpress().GetScripts(
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.PivotGrid },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.HtmlEditor },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Chart },
       new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Report }
        //new Script { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Scheduler }
 )
@Html.DevExpress().GetStyleSheets(
       new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.GridView },
       new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.PivotGrid },
       new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.HtmlEditor },
       new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Editors },
       new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.NavigationAndLayout },
       new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Chart },
       new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Report }
        //new StyleSheet { ExtensionSuite = ExtensionSuite.Scheduler }
 )
@* ---------------------------------JQUERY Scripts for Delete confirmation Starts here --------------------------------*@
<script type="text/javascript">
    // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
    $.fx.speeds._default = 500;
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode",
            width: 250,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons:
            {
                "Delete": function () {
                    $.post(deleteLinkObj[0].href, function (data) {  //Post to action
                        //Check data the return from the middle layer, if it is just true, deletion is successful
                        if (data == '@Boolean.TrueString') {
                            deleteLinkObj.closest("tr").hide('fast'); //Hide Row
                            $("#dialog").dialog("close");   //See it used #dialog instead of (this)  because the scope (context) has changed in the "Delete" callback
                            $(this).empty();
                            $("#StatusMsg").html("Deleted");
                            location.reload();   //refreshes the page
                        }
                        else {

                            //Show the errror on the dialog content. Data is used to show the error
                            //expecting the Error handlers in middle layer will return the meaning ful error message
                            $("#dialog").html(data);
                            //Hide confirmation button inorder to show the user to only the content of error in the same 
                            //dialog box and allow to cancel this dialog
                            $(":button:contains('Delete')").css("display", "none");
                            $("#StatusMsg").html("Not Deleted");
                        }
                        //location.reload();
                    });

                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    //This reset of the Delete button is need since if it wsas invoked and jumped into show error routine,
                    // then that routine would have removed the Delete button.
                    $(":button:contains('Delete')").css("display", "inline");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $("#StatusMsg").html("");
                }
            }
        });

        var deleteLinkObj;
        var deletMsg;
        $('a.inputFakeDelete').click(function () {

            //Here the  message is built using the delete button properties id and name. 
            //So every page calling this jquery need to have the link button embedded with these properties
            //eg: id = Grade, name = the name of the grade from the model
            deletMsg = "Are you sure you want to delete this " + this.id;
            if (this.name == "") {
            }
            else {
                deletMsg = deletMsg + " '" + this.name + "'" //"Are you sure you want to delete the " + (this).id +  " '" + (this).name + "'?";
            }
            deletMsg = deletMsg + "?"


            $("#dialog").html(deletMsg)
            deleteLinkObj = $(this);  //to use in the dialog javascript
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
@*----------------------------------JQUERY Scripts delete confirmation Ends here --------------------------------*@
@*----------------------------------JQUERY Scripts for record cuirrent filer --------------------------------*@
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentValue = 0;
    function handleClick(currentfilter) {
        //alert('Old value: ' + currentValue);
        //alert('New value: ' + currentfilter.value);
        currentValue = currentfilter.value;

        //Redirect the page so that will reload with new parameters 
        window.location = 'http://' + window.location.host + currentValue;  //Add 'http://' since host will not include this

    }
</script>
@*----------------------------------JQUERY Scripts for record cuirrent filer ends here --------------------------------*@
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The error page just says that it cannot find a specific webpage. Customer/Delete

Comment: are all the scripts local?

Comment: Please, post the code on your post. Code in images is not SEO friendly and won't help anybody else.

Comment: jQuery UI attached from remote host?

Comment: I know what the IE developer tools look like - just paste in the error message. Never use a picture of text when you can use text.

Comment: Hi Charlietfl, Yes the scripts are all local. I will put the code in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is was the fix for my problem (and it is a little hard to test as the machine is not my own) but later on we reconfigured .net by using aspnet_regiis.exe and the problem looks like it has disapeared.